# Posting a Tweet without TwitterAPI In Python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

Is there a way to post a tweet using Selenium?

I don't want to create developer account to get API key, because I don't want to give my phone number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Comment: Buy a disposable SIM card and use that. Or ask another developer for an API token.

Comment: You can use a Google Voice phone number to verify your Twitter app too